# Php include file in different folder that includes another file

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP and I've been trying to make a file (`index.php`) include another file (`connect.php`) that includes another file (`config.php`) but they are located in different folders.

This is my directory structure:

```
 > index.php (in the [root]...)
 > connect.php ([root]/admin/)
 > config.php ([root]/admin/)
```

This is what I have so far:

**index.php**

```
include './admin/connect.php'
```

**connect.php**

```
$directory = getcwd();
chdir(__DIR__);
include "config.php";
chdir($directory);
```

This is actually working but somehow I'm not loving the idea of changing the working directory.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Why can't your index just include both?

Comment: Use absolute paths instead. Use `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as the base value, and then include “from” there. That way, it will work no matter where your “main” script is actually located.

Comment: You can use something like `include(__DIR__.'/config.php');` in the  `connect.php` file, similar idea to @CBroe.

Comment: @Rasclatt: Actually, that is even better than using the document root … less characters to type. (Plus, document root can cause problems under certain circumstances, f.e. some hosting providers have it configured in a weird way, and you can never be quite sure if it includes a trailing slash or not …)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put following lines at top of your index.php,

**index.php**

```
<?php

// Define native directory seperator. 
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR);

// Define absolute project root.
define('ROOT', getcwd().DS);

// Define absolute admin folder 
define('ADMIN_ROOT', ROOT.'admin'.DS);

include ADMIN_ROOT.'connect.php';
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php

include ADMIN_ROOT.'config.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `include();` the string inside will lead to varying places depending on certain inputs.

```
+ /var/www/
- index.php
  + /var/www/admin/
  - connect.php
  - config.php
```

You can reference something from the same folder by simply providing a string including the file name.

```
// Include same-folder script
include('config.php');
// Include same-folder subfolder
include('admin/config.php');
```

You can also reference a files absolute position from starting the string with a forward-slash `/` which will take you to the root directory.

```
include('/var/www/admin/connect.php');
```

From within a folder you can go up a folder by using `..` in your string.

```
// Here it is redundant because you are exiting a folder and re-entering it.
include('/var/www/admin/../admin/connect.php');
```

You may also reference your users home directory (whichever user is running your server software) by using a tilde `~`.

```
include('~/admin/connect.php');
```

It is extremely simple for you to include your desired files using a simple reference.

/index.php

```
<?php
  // Here you need to go up a folder to reach the connect script.
  include('admin/connect.php');
?>
```

/admin/connect.php

```
<?php
  // Here config is in the same folder as connect, so it can be referenced as such.
  include('config.php');
?>
```

Comment: I meant: "`//Here config is in the same folder as connect, so it can be referenced as such. include('config.php');`" I ended up using `include __DIR__ ."/config.php";` in connect.php.