# How to include the PHP file that is outside the folder where main PHP file exists?

Tags: php, html, css

This is my directory:

```
Wamp>www>Newlinks
  CSS (folder)
  header.php
  footer.php
    Profiles (folder)
      MainPHPfile.php
```

Now, I want to include the header and footer files into MainPHPfile.php, but it's not working. How to set the path so that it works?

Same problem is with CSS. I want to use CSS files from CSS folder for those header and footer files. Please solve this problem. I shall be thankful to you.

Comment: if you have index.php you should look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095968/php-include-file-in-different-folder-that-includes-another-file/31096380#31096380)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go a directory up with `..` like this:

```
<?php
include '../header.php';
include '../footer.php';
```

Same with CSS.

Comment: Okay, now it includes the PHP files, but the CSS doesn't work :(

Comment: Without knowing your code and structure i could only assume a tag like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/your.css">`

Answer (score 0):

In order to go up a folder, use the `../` relative path, if you need to go down a folder, just writte the relative continuous path. `example/another_folder/file.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `../path/folder/to/file.ext` to go to the previous path. `/path/folder/to/file.ext` to go to the root of your website e.g `/public-html/` or `/htdocs/` .